# Javascript Character Replacement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a translation tool where somebody can enter text into a form and the translation automatically processes with each keystroke into a corresponding form.

The translation is per character in an array. Each Key will be replaced with its corresponding Value pair.

I don't know why the text won't output.

Here is the Code:

```js
var array = {
  'a': 'z',
  'b': 'y',
  'c': 'x',
  'd': 'w',
  'e': 'v',
  'f': 'u',
  'g': 't',
  'h': 's',
  'i': 'r',
  'j': 'q',
  'k': 'p',
  'l': 'o',
  'm': 'n',
  'n': 'm',
  'o': 'l',
  'p': 'k',
  'q': 'j',
  'r': 'i',
  's': 'h',
  't': 'g',
  'u': 'f',
  'v': 'e',
  'w': 'd',
  'x': 'c',
  'y': 'b',
  'z': 'a'
};

var english = document.getElementById('englishform');
var backwards = document.getElementById('backwardsform');

var new_str = english;

for (var key in array) {
  if (!array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    continue;
  }

  new_str = new_str.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), array[key]);
}

english.value = new_str;

english.onkeyup = function() {
  backwards.value = english.value;
};
```

```html
<form action="home.html" method="post">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" placeholder="Enter English" rows="15">
    </textarea>
</form>
<form>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="backwardsform" placeholder="Enter Backwards English" rows="15">
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with non-alphabetic characters? If you are specific enough about how you want it to work, I'll write a full implementation just because this looks fun and I like to teach best practices with little projects like this.

Comment: try to add the code as a snippet if it is a complete one

Comment: @SagarV Make sure if you are making snippet, either it does not throws error. There are cases when users put partial code. Making it as snippet which throws error does more harm.

Comment: it is a syntax error which OP facing I think. `string.replace` @Rajesh

Comment: @SagarV it was a general pointer. And yes, issue is with `new_str = english`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler implementation that doesn't use a map, but mathematically replaces based on each character's ASCII index:

```js
(() => {
  const english = document.getElementById('englishform');
  const backwards = document.getElementById('backwardsform');
  const regexp = /([A-Z])|([a-z])/g;
  const upperBounds = [...'AZ'].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
  const lowerBounds = [...'az'].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));

  function replacer(match, upper, lower) {
    let min, max;
    let value = (upper || lower).charCodeAt(0);

    if (upper) {
      [min, max] = upperBounds;
    } else {
      [min, max] = lowerBounds;
    }

    return String.fromCharCode(max - value + min);
  }

  english.addEventListener('input', () => {
    backwards.value = english.value.replace(regexp, replacer);
  });

  backwards.addEventListener('input', () => {
    english.value = backwards.value.replace(regexp, replacer);
  });
})();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 60px;
}

form, textarea {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="home.html" method="post">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" placeholder="Enter English"></textarea>
</form>
<form>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="backwardsform" placeholder="Enter Backwards English"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: I submitted an answer, and I still think this should be the accepted answer. Nice work.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I want the non-alphabetic characters to be the same. The second textarea should feedback when typing in the first and vice versa. The key-value pairs will be different. For example, I'd also like to make a translator using this particular key-value pair: {'a': 'y', 'b': 'p', 'c': 'l', 'd': 't', 'e': 'a', 'f': 'v', 'g': 'k', h': 'r', 'i': 'e', 'j': 'z', 'k': 'g', 'l': 'm', 'm': 's', 'n': 'h', 'o': 'u', 'p': 'b', 'q': 'x', 'r': 'n', 's': 'c', 't': 'd', 'u': 'i', 'v': 'j', 'w': 'f', 'x': 'q', 'y': 'o', 'z': 'w'}
Do I just need to edit the replacer function to be a key-value pair?

Comment: @MichaelErickson well, no, because it'd have to be the reverse of the key-value pair when translating from backwards to forwards. You'd need two replacer functions if you wanted to take that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
var new_str = english;
```

Change this to:

```
var new_str = english.value;
```